# Flutter hive box not Listenable

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

As part of a ValueListenableBuilder that sets up for a Listview that needs to update when a new entry is added to the db. I'm new to flutter but every tutorial I found says this should work but its says "The method 'listenable' isn't defined for the type 'Box'." Any help or ideas on where im going wrong is a massive help.

(only a section of code as the whole widget is pretty big)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

Widget foodbar(context) => ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: Hive.box<dynamic>('food').listenable(),
    builder: (
      context,
      foodbox,
      _,
    ) {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: foodbox.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final food = foodbox.getAt(index) as FoodMod;
            return;
```

(pubspec.yaml)

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  hive: 1.4.1+1
  hive_flutter: ^0.3.0+2
  path_provider: ^1.3.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  hive_generator: ^0.8.2
  build_runner:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
```

[source](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/598#issuecomment-845127432)